# deleting specific comment that is attached to post vue laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, comments

I am currently creating a website with laravel and i created a comment system with vue. I managed to post comments successfully but i am having a problem with editing and deleting a specific comment. I am trying to somehow retrieve the id of each comment so i can create a method similar to the postComment() i have in the picture below to delete or edit the specific comment. Does anyone have an idea how to do that? 
Thanks in advance

**This is my post page which has the post and the attached comments**

```
    <script>
 const app = new Vue({
    el:'#root',
    data: {
        comments: {},
        commentBox: '',
        post: {!! $post->toJson() !!},
        user: {!! Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->toJson() : 'null' !!},
    },

    mounted() {
        this.getComments();
    },

    methods: {
        getComments(){
            axios.get('/api/posts/'+this.post.id+'/comments')
                 .then((response) => {
                     this.comments = response.data
                 })
                 .catch(function (error) {
                     console.log(error);
                 });
        },
        postComment(){
            axios.post('/api/posts/'+this.post.id+'/comment', {
                api_token: this.user.api_token,
                text: this.commentBox
            })
            .then((response) => {
                this.comments.unshift(response.data);
                this.commentBox = '';
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

        },



    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: It depends what is in your response that’s being returned from the API. After getComments is called you’re assigning an array to ‘comments’.. so if this is an array of objects you’ll access the comment id by this.comment.id if it exists, when looping through the comments with v-for directive. There’s not really enough information here to help properly

Comment: @paddyfields when the getComment() method is called i get the text of the comment, the user who wrote it and the date & time that it was submitted and display each of them using the @{{ }}. When i type @{{ comment.id}} i can get the comment id to display on each comment but i was trying to assign it to a variable so i can use it but unfortunately i couldn't find a way and i'm not sure if i can do that. If i understand correctly what you're saying is inside the deleteComment() method that i will create i need to make a v-for directive?

Comment: Say you want to delete the comment, create a new method called deleteComment, which you pass the id via the onclick of a delete button in your html template, eg) <a v-on:click=“deleteComment(comment.id)”>delete comment</a> ... the comment id is then passed to your method where you can do an API call and handle the delete. V-for is used in the template not in the method, but it sounds like you’re already doing that if you’ve managed to loop out the comments

Comment: @paddyfields i tried that but it didnt work. I added  a button "<button class="btn btn-success" @click.prevent="deleteComment(comment.id)">Delete comment</button>" which passes in the comment id and i created a method deleteComment(comment.id) which takes in the comment.id and then i added "axios.delete('api/posts/'+this.post.id+'/comment'+this.comment.id)
                .then((response) => {
                    this.commentBox = '';
            });". But it didnt work and im guessing because it doesnt recognize the comment id but im not sure

Answer (score 0):

In order to edit or delete a comment. You need the id of that comment. I create a very rough UI below for deleting. Updating requires a bit more complicated handling, but you get the idea:

```
<ul>
    <!-- If the comments is an object, pls use Object.values(comments) -->
    <li v-for="comment in comments">{{comment.text}} <button @click="deleteComment(comment.id)">Delete</button>
</ul>

<script>
 const app = new Vue({
    // ...
    methods: {
        deleteComment(commentId) {
            // ...    
        }
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: i am already using v-for to display the comments. But i am having a problem with the comment id. I added it to a button as you said but when i try and adding it to the method it doesnt work. For example in the deleteComment(comment.id) when i add the id in there i cannot even get the comments to be displayed for some reason and when i press the delete button nothing works. I debugged the code and in the root inside the comments array i have the id the problem is i cannot get it to work

Comment: Do you use vue dev tools? Is the array of comments empty or having data?

Comment: Yes i do. the array has the comment compenents "id, post_id, text, date" etc

Comment: when i write {{comment.id}} i get an error of a "undefidned constant" but when i write @ {{ comment.id }} then i get the comment id printed on my screen. I dont know how to assign that to the button and if you can do that

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the PUT request for upating and Delete for deleting data. I edited your code.

```
 <script>
  const app = new Vue({
    el:'#root',
    data: {
        comments: {},
        commentBox: '',
        post: {!! $post->toJson() !!},
        user: {!! Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->toJson() : 'null' !!},
    },

    mounted() {
        this.getComments();
    },

    methods: {
        deleteComments(){
            axios.delete('/api/posts/'+this.post.id+')
                 .then((response) => {
                    console.log('Success")
                 })
                 .catch(function (error) {
                     console.log(error);
                 });
        },
        updateComment(){
            axios.put('/api/posts/'+this.post.id, this.comments)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log('Success")
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

        },



    }
});

</script>
```

I believe your back-end delete api route is `api/posts/{post}`

Comment: my back-end route is api/post/{post}/comment{comment_id, commentController@destroy} since im trying to only delete a specific comment. I know that i have to use delete for deleting and put for updating but in the way that you made it regarding delete wont it just delete the specific post? Thanks in advance